# Проблема при выгрузке trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите  с устранением ошибки пожалуйста. Вот код:

```
<?php

defined('PHPFOX') or exit('NO DICE!');
include(PHPFOX_DIR_LIB . 'simplehtmldom' . PHPFOX_DS . 'simple_html_dom.php');
class Partner_Component_Controller_Index2 extends Phpfox_Component
{
    public function process()
    {
    $aRows = Phpfox::getLib('database')
        ->select('id, product')             
        ->from(Phpfox::getT('partner'))
        ->execute('getRows');
        foreach ($aRows as $iKey => $aRow)
        {

            $sId = $aRows[$iKey]['id'];
            $sProduct = $aRows[$iKey]['product'];//urlencode($userinput)
            @$aHtml = file_get_html('http://www.dns-shop.ru/search/?q='. urlencode($sProduct));
            @$aDnsshop2 = $aHtml->find('a[class=ec-price-item-link]', 0);
            @$aDnsshop3 = $aDnsshop2->href;
        //echo $aDnsshop2;
            @$aDnsshop4 = 'http://www.dns-shop.ru'. $aDnsshop3;
            @$aDnsshop5 = file_get_html($aDnsshop4);
            @$aDnsshop6 = $aDnsshop5->find('meta[itemprop=price]', 0);
            @$aDnsshop7 = $aDnsshop6->content;
            $update_sql = "UPDATE phpfox_partner SET dnsshoplink='$aDnsshop4', dnsshop='$aDnsshop7' WHERE id=" . $sId;
            mysql_query($update_sql) or die("Ошибка вставки" . mysql_error());
        }
    }
}
?>
```

После обработки второй строки таблицы обращения - ошибка.

Comment: *После обработки второй строки* - это какой? Там где `include(PHPFOX_DIR_LIB...`? Полный текст ошибки приведите

Comment: Простите я имел в виду вторую строку таблицы обращения

Comment: так полный текст ошибки какой? Там номер строки с ошибкой должен быть. `file_get_html` может вернуть false, метод `find`  может вернуть null, а у вас нет соответствующих проверок, отсюда и эти ошибки

Comment: Вот на это он ссылается @$aDnsshop3 = $aDnsshop2->href;

Comment: ну значит метод `find` ничего не нашел, смотрите что возвращается при текущем запросе и правьте ваш код

Comment: в том то и дело что когда вручную подставляю то все нормально